# How does this Python/numpy code achieve white scaling for XYZ->rgb colour space transformation?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am reading [this guide](https://scipython.com/blog/converting-a-spectrum-to-a-colour/) on converting optical spectra to rgb colour coordinates.

I basically understand what the algebra is doing, but the author doesn't really explain the algebra for handling the white point and I can't read the Python/numpy code which does the job

```
import numpy as np

class ColourSystem:

    def __init__(self, red, green, blue, white):

        self.red, self.green, self.blue = red, green, blue
        self.white = white

        # The chromaticity matrix (rgb -> xyz) and its inverse
        self.M = np.vstack((self.red, self.green, self.blue)).T 
        self.MI = np.linalg.inv(self.M)

        # White scaling array
        self.wscale = self.MI.dot(self.white)

        # xyz -> rgb transformation matrix
        self.T = self.MI / self.wscale[:, np.newaxis]
```

The last two lines confuse me. My interpretation is that `self.white` is a column vector, so `self.MI.dot(self.white)` is a matrix-vector multiplication yielding another column vector.

But in that interpretation, the final line reads like *dividing* a matrix by a vector, which makes no sense to me.

What is that final line doing to produce a xyz->rgb matrix by modifying the inverse of the rgb->xyz matrix?

Comment: My understanding is that self.wscale[:, np.newaxis] is transforming the column vector (of shape (3,)) into a 3x1 matrix (of shape (3,1)). When you then divide, broadcasting is applied, therefore you are doing an elementwise division of the 3x3 matrix MI by the 3x3 matrix obtained by repeating 3 times the wscale column vector.

Comment: "broadcasting"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, this is more of an answer to the comment than to the original question, but long and with some code so it doesn't fit there. Let me rewrite a self-contained code snippet that does the same thing you are asking (with initialization numbers taken from the link you gave):

```
import numpy as np
def xyz_from_xy(x, y):
    """Return the vector (x, y, 1-x-y)."""
    return np.array((x, y, 1-x-y))

red=xyz_from_xy(0.67, 0.33)
green=xyz_from_xy(0.21, 0.71)
blue=xyz_from_xy(0.15, 0.06)
white=xyz_from_xy(0.3127, 0.3291)

# The chromaticity matrix (rgb -> xyz) and its inverse
M = np.vstack((red, green, blue)).T 
MI = np.linalg.inv(M)
# White scaling array
wscale = MI.dot(white)
# xyz -> rgb transformation matrix
T = MI / wscale[:, np.newaxis]
```

The values this writes in T is the following matrix:

> array([[ 6.20584986, -1.71746142, -1.04788582],
>
> [-2.71554014,  5.51336937,  0.09687197],
>
> [ 0.19384968, -0.39357359,  2.9841102 ]])

Now, how is this computed and how is broadcasting involved?

As the name "vstack" suggests, `M` is just stacking the red, green, and blue vectors one on the other:

> array([[ 6.70000000e-01,  2.10000000e-01,  1.50000000e-01],
>
> [ 3.30000000e-01,  7.10000000e-01,  6.00000000e-02],
>
> [-5.55111512e-17,  8.00000000e-02,  7.90000000e-01]])

(where, according to the function xyz_from_xy, the last component is always just one minus the sum of the first two). MI is its inverse:

> array([[ 1.72809198, -0.47824736, -0.29179615],
>
> [-0.81013052,  1.64481044,  0.02889994],
>
> [ 0.08203853, -0.16656308,  1.26289621]])

And, as you correctly mentioned, `wscale` is just a vector (one-dimensional) obtained as the scalar product of `MI` with `white=array([0.3127, 0.3291, 0.3582])`:

> array([0.27846178, 0.29833126, 0.42320696])

Now, to broadcasting. First, `wscale[:, np.newaxis]` is just the same thing as wscale, but reshaped with shape `(3,1)`:

> array([[0.27846178],
>
> [0.29833126],
>
> [0.42320696]])

(the same effect could be achieved by writing: `wscale.reshape(3,1)`). When you do an arithmetic operation between `MI` (that has shape (3,3)) and this other object (of shape (3,1)), be it sum, multiplication, division, or even something apparently weirder like **, it just does so element-wise. But since the dimensions differ, it tries to "broadcast", namely every dimension that is equal to 1 is made to be equal to the corresponding dimension in the other object (3, in this case) by repeating the same vector many times. Explicitly, you're dividing MI elementwise by the matrix obtained by horizontally repeating wscale three times. You would obtain the same result in a more verbose way by writing:

```
T = MI / np.hstack((wscale.reshape(3,1), wscale.reshape(3,1), wscale.reshape(3,1)))
```

If you wanted to do matrix operations like a dot product you'd need to explicitly write `MI.dot(wscale[:, np.newaxis])` (which in this case would return a (3,1) shaped tensor). But this is not what is done: the result of `T = MI / wscale[:, np.newaxis]` is:

> array([[ 6.20584986, -1.71746142, -1.04788582],
>
> [-2.71554014,  5.51336937,  0.09687197],
>
> [ 0.19384968, -0.39357359,  2.9841102 ]])

This is just the result of dividing elementwise any column of `MI` by `wscale`. For example, looking at the first one, if we do `MI[:,0] / wscale` we indeed get:

> array([ 6.20584986, -2.71554014,  0.19384968])

i.e. the first column.

Comment: So if we consider `MI` to be three column vectors `(a b c)`, we divide each of the x-components of a, b, and c by the x-component of `wscale`, and likewise for the other components?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens!